# Jenkins error: Unable to configure handler 'debug_file_handler'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I run Jenkins job that supposes to output the logs artifacts.

```
post {
    always {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'logs/my-job-name_*.log' , fingerprint: true
    }
}
```

I got this error in the Console Output

> Error in Logging Configuration. Using default configs.
> Unable to configure handler 'debug_file_handler'

And the artifacts don't created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone runs the Jenkins job from the VM terminal with the root user.
[image]

The root user was the owner of the logs,
so the further Jenkins runs (with the user jenkins) couldn't write to this log.
I deleted the log folder and it worked out.